# navigation.navigate is not a function problem in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

hello i tried to use react Navigation from its docs but i have a problem.the error is navigation.navigate is undefined here is my declaration my routes:

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,

} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';



import AboutUs from './AboutUs'
import Navigations from './Navigations'
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
    const Stack = createStackNavigator();
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="App" component={App} />
                <Stack.Screen name="AboutUs" component={AboutUs} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Navigations" component={Navigations} />

            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

and here is my Button to navigate:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
    View, Text,
    Button
} from 'react-native'


const AboutUs = ({ navigation }) => {
    return <View>
        <Text>About us page</Text>
        <Button title='press me' onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Navigations', name = 'aliiiiiiiiis') }} />
    </View>
}
export default AboutUs;
```

Comment: try to put a "this" infront of navigation.. so this.navigation.navigate

Comment: is functional component this not exist, I think the problem is you declare const Stack=createStackNavigator(); inside App component, you should declare outside of the components like in the example from the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation.

Comment: try define stack out of main functional component, and see what happens.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi what should i do?

Comment: It will works, just run your metro with removing cache, may helps: ```yarn start --reset-cache```